# How to set Azure Powershell's API Version for Role Creation

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I'm using Azure to host a series of services and need to create some custom roles for RBAC. I'm running into errors when trying to run the appropriate commands to create the roles.

There are a number of good documentation [sources](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-manage-access-powershell/) and [walkthroughs](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2015/12/10/custom-roles-in-azure-rbac-is-now-ga/) on how to do this, and it seems easy in theory, but I keep running into issues running the Powershell Commandlet:

```
New-AzureRmRoleDefinition -InputFile [pathtojsondoc]
```

The input file is just json describing the role

```
"Name":  "Test Role",    
"IsCustom":  true,
"Description":  "Role Description",
"Actions":  [
   "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/read"
            ],
"NotActions":  [ ],
"AssignableScopes":  [ ]
```

}

When calling the `New-AzureRmRoleDefinition` function I receive the following error:

> New-AzureRmRoleDefinition : InvalidApiVersionParameter: The api-version '2015-07-01' is invalid. The supported versions are '2016-09-01,2016-07-01,2016-06-01,2016-02-01,2015-11-01,2015-01-01,2014-04-01-preview,2014-04-01,2014-01-0

I'm looking for a resolution to either fix the call as is so it succeeds, or a workaround for creating custom roles.

Comment: Your "AssignableScopes" should not be empty. I have tested the command with `"AssignableScopes":  [ "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" ]`. It works perfectly. What's the version of your Azure PowerShell? And, are you using the global Azure Environment?

Comment: Sorry,  the sample was empty, but the actual run has the value. I removed it to keep my subscription GUID out of the code. I'm running on the global infrastructure, US west to be specific and I'm using the September 28 release of the tools.

Comment: You shouldn't need to specify the apiVersion for the cmdlets - something seems off...  Try doing a Get-Module -Name AzureRM.Resources and see what version you have (should be 3.2 I think)

Comment: @bmoore-msft. I agree it seems off.  Manifest 3.2.0 according to the Get-Module command.

Comment: Ok, file an issue here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues and I'll ask around to see who can help figure out what's going on...

Comment: @bmoore-msft bug submitted. Also, for good measure ran the same command from a new Azure Windows box and got the same output. Debug output shows the URI being called is appended with an ?api-version=2015-07-01 query string.

Comment: thanks for filing the bug...

Comment: No problem. If you find any workarounds please let me know. This is a blocking issue and an overall security concern for us.

Comment: @bmoore-msft any update? This is becoming a security issue for us.

Comment: there was a new version of Azure PowerShell released yesterday, try installing that and see if it fixes it (it did for me)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the error I was receiving was a bad error message causing an improper diagnosis.

After updating to the latest version of Azure PowerShell I received the same error - so I did a bit more digging and found an updated code sample.

I was setting the assignable scopes in the file to be to specific resource groups using the format `/subscriptions/*******/myresourcegroupname` but the correct format is `/subscriptions/*******/resourceGroups/myresourcegroupname` notice the extra `/resourceGroups/` path.